# "An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code" error

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to make a web service in Visual Studio 2013 application.

I get the following error : "An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code".

WCF Service `Web.Config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8095/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Website Project Service Client `Web.Config`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8095/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Remove the bindings and client section from the system.WebServer section entirely, they would only belong in a system.ServiceModel section.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have copy pasted a lot of stuff into the wrong places.

At a simple minimum, your WCF Service config's system.ServiceModel section should look more like this...

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="Service1">
        <endpoint address="Service1.svc" name="Service1Endpoint"
           binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" />
        <host>
         <baseAddresses>
           <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8095/Service1.svc" />
         </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Try adjusting your config to this, and then viewing the url using a web browser. If you see the page that lets you generate a WSDL, then you only need to create a client binding that matches.

An example of a client configuration would be something like this...

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
  </bindings>
  <client>
   <endpoint address="http://localhost:8095/Service1.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"    
    name="MyServiceClient" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Then to create the in-code client, your code would look something like this...

```
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>("MyServiceClient");
var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
```

WCF configuration can be painful at times, due to all the potential settings combinations. It often takes a bit of tweaking to get it working the way you expect.